# Removing NAN elements from multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to know how to removing nan elements from multidimensional numpy array.

For example, I want to convert this array

```
x = array([[ 1., nan,  2.],
          [ 3.,  4., nan]])
```

to

```
x = array([[ 1.,  2.],
           [ 3.,  4.]])
```

I found some similar ways, but looks different what I want:

1.

```
x = x[~np.isnan(x)]
```

But this way remove array shape information.

```
>>> x[~np.isnan(x)]
array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```

2. 

These are similar questions, but I don't want remove row or column including nan's, I want to just remove nan elements.

- [Removing NaNs in numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120626/removing-nans-in-numpy-arrays)
- [How to remove all rows in a numpy.ndarray that contain non-numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453141/how-to-remove-all-rows-in-a-numpy-ndarray-that-contain-non-numeric-values)

Comment: What do you expect if lengths of _rows_ are different after removing `nan`s?

Comment: A ragged array is ok.  I can handle `VisibleDeprecationWarning`.